# running rabbitmq in container on centos 9 is unresponsive

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using docker ce on centos 9.
I installed rabbitmq 3.7.4.
Commands like "rabbitmq-plugins list" executes in 10 minutes.
No ssl is configured , just plain 5672.
There is no exception in logs.
What can it be?
Thanks.

Comment: How to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Hi , I saw your reply late. You run rabbit container as follows: sudo docker run -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -v /opt/docker/rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq --name rabbit rabbitmq:3.7.4 and enter into container as docker exec -ti rabbit /bin/bash and once in it , you run "rabbitmq-plugins list" without quotes

Answer (score 0):

Using rabbitmq tag 3.8.34 somehow worked.